# Zappar error : "WARNING in ./node_modules/@mediapipe/tasks-vision/vision_bundle.mjs Module Warning"

Tags: reactjs, three.js

so i am trying to implement the @zappar/zappar-react-three-fiber library but i am seeing this warning every time and do not have any response in the localhost(no AR objecct is there , I am using image tracking) : Compiled with warnings.

Failed to parse source map from '/home/manan/Apps/pwa-ar/my-ar-app/node_modules/@mediapipe/tasks-vision/vision_bundle_mjs.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/manan/Apps/pwa-ar/my-ar-app/node_modules/@mediapipe/tasks-vision/vision_bundle_mjs.js.map'

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in ./node_modules/@mediapipe/tasks-vision/vision_bundle.mjs
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/manan/Apps/pwa-ar/my-ar-app/node_modules/@mediapipe/tasks-vision/vision_bundle_mjs.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/manan/Apps/pwa-ar/my-ar-app/node_modules/@mediapipe/tasks-vision/vision_bundle_mjs.js.map'

webpack compiled with 1 warning
^C

so i am trying to implement the @zappar/zappar-react-three-fiber library but i am seeing this warning every time and do not have any response in the localhost(no AR objecct is there , I am using image tracking) i am expecting to see a sphere when the image is tracked